# SharePoint Online Managed Path

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, rest, api, m365

Does anyone know how to get this information through rest API or PowerShell? I wanted to know if the tenant I am working with is using "/teams/" or "/sites/". I am creating an application that needs to know this setup for my client.

[image: How to set the default path for creating new sites]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no such function or api to get the setting of the default url currently.